# General Fibonacci, why is it overflowing?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a general fibonacci series where the starting values can be variable, depending on what the user wants. For example, instead of starting with values 0, 1, or 1, 1, as it usually does, it can start with 3, 6, or 10, 21, or whatever the user wants. We then want to get the nth value of that series.

I tried my code for a = 10 and b = 21, and I wanted a big value, however it didn't work. So I started checking where the problem was. With those starting values: for n = 37, 38, 39, the output should be 405812042, 656617677, 1062429719 respectively. When I run my code for values n = 37 and n = 38, both answers are correct. However when I try 39, this is the value I get: 62429712.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned long long a, b, hn, value;
  int scenarios;

  scanf("%d", &scenarios);

  for (int i = 0; i < scenarios; i++){
    scanf("%lld%lld%lld", &a, &b, &hn);
    if (hn == 1)
      value = a;
    else if (hn == 2)
      value = b;
    else{
      for (int j = 3; j <= hn; j++){
        value = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = value;
      }
    //value %= 1000000007;
    }
    printf("%lld\n", value);
  }


}
```

EDIT: According to the problem specification, the answer should be module 1000000007. The output I get if I get the 514th value is 2903631044495864380, and to be honest I don't know how to verify this value. If I do 2903631044495864380 mod 1000000007, my answer is 170447212, but according to the problem this answer should be 859861000. Any idea how to verify this?

Comment: `%lld`s should be `%llu`s

Comment: Cannot reproduce:  https://ideone.com/aJCFKc Although as noted the format specified for unsigned long long is not lld, the code still works as expected

Comment: The maximal value of some `unsigned long long`  is only 2**64 - 1 on my machine since they have 64 bits.

Comment: You may want to use [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) with [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: The sum modulo N is equal to the (sum of each of its components modulo N) modulo N.  So, simply keep `a` and `b` valid modulo 1000000007 (did I count the zeros correctly?) and add them and take the result modulo 100000007.  Those values won't exceed 2^31-1 when added, so 32-bit arithmetic should be OK.

Comment: `62429712` **is** `1062429719 % 1000000007`. You've commented the remainder operation out but that is not the code you're running. Voting to close as "unable to reproduce".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
scanf("%lld%lld%lld", &a, &b, &hn);
```

to this:

```
scanf("%llu%llu%llu", &a, &b, &hn);
```

Change this:

```
printf("%lld\n", value);
```

to this:

```
printf("%llu\n", value);
```

since these variables are of type `unsigned long long`.

---

EDIT

It seems like (from your edit) you need to change this:

```
value = a + b;
```

to this:

```
value = (a + b) % 1000000007;
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved it, but apparently I have to find a more efficient algorithm now, only executes half of the subtasks. But thanks anyways ;)

Comment: First you need to get it right, then optimize @ch15, you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You misinterpreted the point where you should calculate the modulo according to your exercise.

You don't compute the end sum before doing modulo, but you apply modulo to the intermediate results:

```
for (int j = 3; j <= hn; j++)
{
    value = (a + b) % 1000000007; // there
    a = b;
    b = value;
}
```

Also, change your scan/print format to `'%llu'`, as @gsamaras suggested.

Comment: Right, I figured that out after the edit of the OP. Nice catch.